# What's the best way to ask for user feedback about a specific element/section in a website?

Tags: website-design, forms, popup, ratings, user-feedback

I'm working a feedback form for a clinical platform which is used by health care providers (mainly doctors). The website has a patient dashboard where the doctor can see the patients clinical record like his test scores and more.

Now, we would like to ask for user feedback (mainly from doctors) on a specific patient detail on the website to understand how much the info shown is in alignment with their clinical judgment.

Here's what I have created:
[image]

A few points that bother me are:

- I feel it's **not good to have general feedback** form since here we need feedback on specific info shown in the page
- The response from the user to this is critical since it is about a clinical score. Still, **need the option to ignore/hide the feedback prompt** forever in that page
- The feedback prompt/form **should not hinder other regular actions** of the user in the website
- To **get more precise feedback** it's necessary to rate the experience in a scale from 1 to 5
- Will **using emoji's to rate** something avoid confusion and be more clear?
- Due to **limited space in the section**, I used a simple Yes/No question within the section and on choosing a response he would be presented with a popup with a detailed form (both Yes and No options)

Comment: Have you thought through a later scenario where you might need feedback on some other element also? Do you get me?

Comment: @Kishan Yes, we might need to have a similar feedback mechanism on other elements too and maybe a general feedback form like normal websites but, currently this is our priority. We really want to know how the system-generated score is helping the clinician.

Comment: Exactly my point. If you might need similar feedback mechanism on other elements too, then you can't do this method right? B'cz it will be repetition even though placed on different elements. And doesn't feel good asking for too much feedback that to separately.

Comment: @Kishan That's a valid point. I guess then maybe this would be the only element in this screen which would have this feature. There might be an additional general feedback option added later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really good example from one of the food ordering site: [Swiggy](https://www.swiggy.com) where once you order your food and next time you are on the site, the highlighted area pops in at the bottom right corner without actually blocking me from using the site. And if you click on it, the review is collected just in 2 clicks.

There is still a seperate section in the Help Center if you want to leave a descriptive feedback but this is one way of we can actually collect 'Non-Irritating User Feedbacks'

[image]

Comment: I like the idea but in the case of Swiggy they only have hotels/food listed and the feedback is for the user's primary action of ordering food. In my case, the feedback that needs to be collected is actually for a section in the dashboard which represents critical patient info.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use two elements:

- Show/Hide feedbacks - one switch for a whole page.
- Estimation - one element for each info block in a page.

Show/hide switch could be located at page's header and made visibly emphasized showing importance of this feature. When enabled it makes all feedback blocks in a page visible and user can leave feedbacks. When disabled it will keep page in usual workable state. This element could change its attributes depending on feedbacks already made by user - red color if no fidbacks and green color if all feedbacks are provided as well as 'Thank you' text for this.

Estimation block is single button icon in a header of each information block - green check mark if feedback is provided and red question mark otherwise. Clicking the button will activate your desired feedback form.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very reasonable to me.

I think this unobtrusive way of asking for feedback is quite common.

Regarding the rating:
I guess you want to find out how accurate they find the score right? (At least that's what the message suggests on the overview). But then in the popup it's feels more like a "how do you feel about the feature". 
I'd phrase it more precisely in the popup and maybe also use a score to rate it. (I strongly disagree..... I strongly agree)

Answer (score -3):

I would solve this with two icons and a rating bar:

- [Rating bar](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/) `from - to +` : the rating bar helps to avoid any popup level status.
- First icon: `write us more`, *to get more precise feedback if necessary*.
- Second icon: `close this form`, *the immediate option to ignore/hide the feedback prompt*.

[image]

Comment: Your example is more complicated and highlighted then the actual element that should get rated and its not transparent at all, i would need to hover/click those buttons to understand what they do..